# RemoteCertificateNameMismatch. The issue with the name

Tags: wcf, security, ssl

Do not advice to return true from the validation callback. It's a bad practice. Because of I don't know the best practice of a cerfificate validation I want to rely on the default implementation, but I quite don't understand what name of a server certificate should be specified if the client tries to connect to "https://192.168.0.64/Company/ServiceReference.svc/MainService"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your server is being accessed by IP address, then you'd need a certificate that is issued by a trusted certification authority, is not yet expired and is named to match your IP address.  In your case, it appears this would be 192.168.0.64.  Generally speaking though, it's preferable to use a host or DNS name as you may not be able to control whether the IP address of your server changes.  If the IP were to change, your certificate would then be invalid because the name would no longer match.